# Trying to intercept jdbcOperations and return fixed value with byte buddy

Tags: java, spring, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I am trying to intercept a call to JdbcOperations using byte buddy in conjunction with spring.

I have two classes.

Application.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        premain(null, ByteBuddyAgent.install());
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.is(JdbcOperations.class))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                    @Override
                    public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {
                        return builder.method(named("queryForList"))
                                .intercept(FixedValue.value(Collections.emptyList()));
                    }
                }).installOn(instrumentation);
    }
}
```

And

DemoRunner.java

```
    @Component
    public class DemoRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    public DemoRunner(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
         List<Map<String,Object>> resultSet = jdbcOperations.queryForList("SELECT * FROM COUNTRY");

         for(Map<String, Object> result : resultSet) {
             System.out.println(result);
         }

    }
}
```

I can see that the code runs, but it doesn't return the fixed value like I expected it to. Does anybody have any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With `ElementMatchers.is(JdbcOperations.class)`, you are loading the `JdbcOperations` class. Without retransformation, this class will not be instrumented since it is already loaded when the agent is installed.

Rather use `ElementMatchers.named("pkg.of.JdbcOperations")`.